# Script for copy range from a sheet onto another, delete copied range and paste new formulas from a third sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to develop a script to do the following on google spreadsheets:

1) Copy the range B3:K102 on Tab Source1  on spreadsheet 1.

2) Paste the copied range (as values) onto the last available row of Tab Destination1 on Spreadsheet 2.

3) Clear the range B3:K102 on spreadsheet 1.

4) Copy range C3:K102 on Tab 'Source2' spreadsheet 1.

5) Paste the copied range from 'Source2' onto 'Source1!B3:K102'(as formulas).

Below is the script that Im trying and can't make it work. PLEASE HELP!

Notice that I have little to no clue on what Im doing, I got this script from a friend who know's a little bit, but he's no longer able to help me. So if anyone could please help me by correcting the mistakes and adding what it's missing, I will really appreciate if you could paste the entire final script so I don't mess it up.

THANKS A LOT!

```
    function Copy() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19BsivpPDO8ov3tHXslCzNQi0cB8YeP1gQ-5Zt-4Eb64');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Source1');
  var range = ss.getRange('B3:K102');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tVnIMNQ7oE8YuxLU2KpBSL-Py3T8IqJwV6j59Pfo3j0');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Destination1');
  var endOfFile = ts.getLastRow();
  var cantColumns = 10;

  for (var i = 0; i < cantColumns; i++) {
    endOfFile = endOfFile + 1

    for (var cont = 1; cont < ss.getLastColumn(); cont++) {
      ts.getRange(endOfFile, cont + 1).setValue(data[i][cont -1]);
    }
  }

  range.clearContent();

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19BsivpPDO8ov3tHXslCzNQi0cB8YeP1gQ-5Zt-4Eb64');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName(‘Source2’);

  var range = ss.getRange(‘C3:K102’);

  var data = range.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19BsivpPDO8ov3tHXslCzNQi0cB8YeP1gQ-5Zt-4Eb64');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName(‘Source1’);

  var endOfFile = ts.getLastRow();

  var cantColumns = 9;

  for (var i = 0; i < cantColumns; i++) {
    endOfFile = endOfFile + 1
    // Recorremos la fila y vamos insertando los valores
    for (var cont = 1; cont < ss.getLastColumn(); cont++) {
      ts.getRange(endOfFile, cont + 1).setValue(data[i][cont -1]);

}
```

Comment: are you going to use this just once? Is your data going to always lie in the same Range as you've specified?

Answer (score 1):

This sample script may not be what you want since I cannot see your sample sheet. So if this isn't what you want, feel free to tell me.

When it imports many data to cells, "setValues()" is faster than "setValue()". https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

"getValues()" can retrieve the values of cells. "getFormulas()" can retrieve the formulas of cells. In this sample, both values and formulas are retrieved and copy from Source2 to Source1.

For copying from Source2 to Source1, do you want to copy the data to last row of Source1 or to 'B3:K102'? At current sample, it's last row of Source1 like your script. If Source1 has cells (less than 102) except for 'B3:K102', formulas from Source2 may not work at Source1.

Sample script :

```
function Copy() {
  var srcs = '19BsivpPDO8ov3tHXslCzNQi0cB8YeP1gQ-5Zt-4Eb64';
  var dest = '1tVnIMNQ7oE8YuxLU2KpBSL-Py3T8IqJwV6j59Pfo3j0';
  var srcs_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcs);
  var dest_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dest);
  var src1 = srcs_ss.getSheetByName('Source1');
  var src2 = srcs_ss.getSheetByName('Source2');
  var dest = dest_ss.getSheetByName('Destination1');

  var src1_range = src1.getRange('B3:K102');
  var src1_f = src1_range.getFormulas();
  var src1_dat = src1_range.getValues();
  src1_f.forEach(function(e1, i1){
    e1.forEach(function(e2, i2){
      if (e2 != "") src1_dat[i1][i2] = e2;
    });
  });
  src1_range.clearContent();
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(), 2, src1_dat.length, src1_dat[0].length).setValues(src1_dat);
  var src2_dat = src2.getRange('C3:K102').getValues();
  src1.getRange(src1.getLastRow(), 2, src2_dat.length, src2_dat[0].length).setValues(src2_dat);
}
```